# Tcp raw packets

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, sniffing

I use PcapDotnet wrapper for sniff packets but it show just ip raw packets 
for example at clientside i send that packet

```
 client_.Send(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("test"));
```

and at serverside i want to capture "test" but packet.Buffer show different 66 bytes.Can i get just "test" packets ?

```
  private static void PacketHandler(Packet packet)
    {
        IpV4Datagram ip = packet.Ethernet.IpV4;
        TcpDatagram tcp = ip.Tcp;

        if (tcp.DestinationPort == 28001 || tcp.SourcePort == 28001)
        {
            File.AppendAllText("return.txt", ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(packet.Buffer));
            Console.WriteLine(ip.Source + ":" + tcp.SourcePort + " -> " + ip.Destination + ":" + tcp.DestinationPort);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
File.AppendAllText("return.txt", ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(packet.Buffer));
```

is printing ALL the binary, including the IPv4 header and the TCP header.

try just:

```
File.AppendAllText("return.txt", ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(tcp.Payload??));
```

Comment: i used packetDotNet wrapper and i received correct packets with PayLoad
((packet.PayloadPacket).PayloadPacket).PayloadData,